# Mongo find transform to different object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am kind of new to Mongo and have been experiment with Mongoose for Node.js

My question is specifically about the way the results are formed on a 'find'.
Let's say, the schema is as below with three attributes.

```
 var schema = {
    attr1: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    attr2: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    attr3: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
```

We would search for all entries with 'attr1' as 'value1' as below

```
dataModel.find({'attr1':'value1'}, {attr2:1, attr3:1, _id:0}, resultsFunction)
```

'resultsFunction' would receive the result doc in the form of an array of all the objects. Let's say we get two results and it looks something like this

```
[  { attr2: value1 ,
     attr3: value2 }, 
   { attr2: value3,
     attr3: value4 }]
```

Here's what I am struggling with. I do not want the resultant object(s) to have the same attribute names as the schema. Instead, I want it to be transformed to a custom object

```
[  { customAttr2: value1 ,
     customAttr3: value2 }, 
   { customAttr2: value3,
     customAttr3: value4 }]
```

Is there a way of searching and forming such objects from the Mongodb's API? (rather than writing my own transforms/functions which may impact performance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataModel.aggregate([{$match:{'attr1':'value1'}}, {$project:{customAttr2:"$attr2", customAttr3:"$attr3", _id:0}}], resultsFunction)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. I'll explore aggregate more. Looks like a powerful one.